# Change in mongodb from 3.5.0 to 4.0.6?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm working on a program that was delayed for a while and was written using an older version of mongodb. When I downloaded the new mongobd (4.0.6) and updated the dependencies in my pom every instance of .getDatabase() has errored out. the only other option I can find online is getDB, but that was deprecated before even 3.0. Does anyone know whats going wrong here?

```
public class DataManager
{
    private MongoClient mongo;
    private MongoDatabase db;

    // only used for saving results for legacy OGS Viewer app
    //private final String ogsViewerDbIp = "108.25.358.56";
    private final String ogsViewerDbIp = "108.25.358.65";

    public DataManager(String uri, String dbName) {
        mongo = new MongoClient(uri);
        db = mongo.getDatabase(dbName);
    }
```

Comment: check the changelog before you upgrade

Comment: What do you mean by "getDatabase() errored out"? What's the error message?

Comment: Kevin - Essentially getDatabase() is not in the API for this version of mongodb. The only other call similar in the API is getDB() which is deprecated. For now I've just gone back to an older version of MongoDB that has getDatabase() available